# Which one is more correct and natural: "the country of Canada", "the country Canada", or "Canada country"?

Tags: articles

Which one is more correct and natural: *the country of Canada*, *the country Canada*, or *Canada country*? For example:

> We will learn a lot about **the country of Canada** in the next lesson.
>
> We will learn a lot about **the country Canada** in the next lesson.
>
> We will learn a lot about **Canada country** in the next lesson.

Comment: In nearly all contexts the "more correct and natural" form is simply ***Canada***. Everyone knows it's a country, without needing to be reminded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "the country of Canada" is the most natural. "The country Canada" is possible too, but less natural. "Canada country" sounds wrong. 
 Even more natural would be simply "We will learn a lot about Canada in the next lesson.", unless the group doesn't already know that Canada is a country.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the word **country**. You can just say

> "we will learn a lot about Canada in the next lesson"

But if you insist on it, you can say

> "we will learn about the country of Canada in the next lesson"